# Kendo UI Gantt - Custom Task Edit Template

Tags: kendo-ui, telerik, gantt-chart, kendo-gantt

I have created a custom template for a task using this example:

http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/gantt#configuration-editable.template

```
<script id="editor" type="text/x-kendo-template">
   <h3>Edit meeting</h3>
   <p><label>Title: <input name="title" /></label></p>
   <p><label>Start: <input data-role="datetimepicker" name="start" /></label></p>
   <p><label>End: <input data-role="datetimepicker" name="end" /></label></p>
</script>
```

Now I need to add a 'Resources - Assign' button, just like the one in this example (Edit Task Form):
http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/gantt/resources

What do I need to do to create this button? I can't find any API documentation for this part of the Gantt control.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few steps needed to accomplish this.
First, add something like this to your Kendo template:

```
<div>
  <label for='resources'>Resources:</label>
  <div class='k-gantt-resources' style='display: none;'>
  </div>
  <div class='k-edit-field' data-container-for='resources'>
    <a class='k-button' href='\\#'>Assign</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Next, you'll want to add the following two event handlers to the options when you initialize the widget:

```
edit: editHandler,
save: saveHandler
```

Finally, you'll want to create the two handlers referenced above.  You are basically intercepting the default functionality and opening the popup yourself, then saving the results when complete (if they were modified).

```
var resoucesdEdited = false;

function editHandler(e)
{
    var gantt = e.sender;
    resoucesdEdited = false;

    if (e.task)
    {
        e.container.on('click', 'div[data-container-for="resources"] > a', function (event)
        {
            event.preventDefault();
            resoucesdEdited = true;
            gantt._createResourceEditor(e.container.find('div.k-gantt-resources'), e.task);
        });
    }
}

function saveHandler(e)
{
    if (e.task && resoucesdEdited)
    {
        this._updateAssignments(e.task.get("id"), e.task.get(this.resources.field));
    }
}
```

I'm glad you asked this question because it's something I needed to know too, and you're right, the Telerik/Kendo documentation doesn't mention anything on how to do this!

Comment: Thank you very much! You saved my day. It is unable to find any information about _createResourceEditor or _updateAssignments functions in the net. How did you find them? Can you suggest any tools?

Comment: I dug around the kendo library files and found some information, but honestly I had to go to Telerik support for other answers.  I'm a paid Telerik Devcraft user so I get tech support from them.  Not sure if you use the free or paid version, but if you have the option, their support is great and they always get back to you within 24 hours.